# Are there any widget to tell whether I'm still connected to the internet?

Tags: network

I have an unreliable 3G tethered connection. It breaks when shut window blinds, close a door or when I'm moving around the place.

What I'm really looking for is an icon / indicator whether I'm connected to the internet.

Actually I tried some solutions such as [Surplus Meter](http://www.skoobysoft.com/utilities/utilities.html) and iStatNano desktop widget but this is not what I'm looking for.

Ideally I would like to **ping some service every 5 secs** to see if I'm still online... Are you aware of any solutions providing that feature?

[image: istat nano widget]

Comment: Do you have Growl installed?

Comment: I may have... OK... Will give it a try, see what options are available :)

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult to write a short shell script with ping in a loop and write a growl message whenever the reachability of a selected host changes.